# rxjs map method inquire

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to reactive. I'm trying to map an observable array from a Firebase database but when using the map method, the property should be an any array but it the method ask for any:

```
ngOnInit () {

    this.countries=this.af.database.list('/countries').map(resp=>{
        resp.map(...) //   <--- not working since resp is not an array
        return resp;
      })

  }
```

resp should be an array but intellisense marks it as any so I cannot map resp. Has the map methos an overload?

Comment: can you post error you get?

Comment: And json response please

Comment: I don't have an error but I cannot map resp since I don't receive an array of any, but any. For this reason I ask if map has overloads.

Comment: Look what @tibbus answered you

Comment: So what exactly IS resp if not an array? Why do you want to map that? What's the goal?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the response is **NOT** a json and needs to be parsed first.

Something like :

```
this.countries=this.af.database.list('/countries').map(resp=>{
    let parsedResp = resp.json();

    parsedResp.map(...) //   <--- not working since resp is not an array
    return parsedResp ;
  })
```